# Dynamic validation list in Excel

Tags: excel, validation

I have an issue regarding data validation in Excel, namely how to dynamically set the validation source.

I have three tables, where the first contains a product ID and a product name. The second table contains a product ID together with a serial number. A third table has three columns; one for product ID, one for serial number and a description for e.g. error reporting.

What I want to do is related to the third column where I select the product ID in a drop-down box which is linked to the first table. This works perfectly fine. The second column though, must only allow serial numbers related to the product ID selected according to the relationship in the second table. Hence, the data validation list must be dynamically generated by the input in the first column.

The reason for having it in Excel is due corporate reasons and personally I'd use an SQL-database for this very issue. E.g. if I were to use SQL-syntax to generate the validation list, the corresponding SQL-statement would be:

```
SELECT serialNumber WHERE productId = 12345;
```

I've tried using the `INDEX-MATCH`, but unfortunately `MATCH` only returns a scalar value rather than an array. I have not come across array functions prior to today, but I assume such might be included in order to accomplish this and have tried a bit without success.

If I somehow were to acquire an array returning the row numbers where there is a match, the INDEX-function would accomplish my needs, I presume.

My question is therefore, is there a method to acquire an array of matched values or can my problem be solved using a more elegant solution? If it could be of value if it can be made without VBA, also for corporate security reasons.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a couple ways to do this. Do you have very many product ID's? Then just set a different table for each, or sort them and use validation only within each id, which would be the easiest solution. If you have too many to reasonably do this, can you add a column to your table? I've created dynamically populated tables, although what I do isn't elegant, it gets the job done. If the first way doesn't work, let me know and I'll try to describe my solution for a dynamic table.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718125/using-concatenate-in-the-validation-source-field-to-refer-to-a-named-table/28718219#28718219

Comment: From what I understand, your first suggestion is to create a unique table for each product ID to work around the problem? That is an option, as you say, if the number of unique products is reasonably low. In my case, however this solution gives rise to a bit too much manual work which in turn will make the validation procedure less effective, in my mind.

I can add a column to my table, there's no problem. I think that i kind of understand what you are ought to do with a dynamic table and it sounds to me that it's a more preferable solution to my problem. :-)